# Prevent MouseEvent on Angular directive from triggering change detection

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I am working on an Angular project where a directive needs to react to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. it needs to update the CSS of the host element where it is used.

Consider the contrived example below:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMouseEvents]',
})
export class MouseEventsDirective {
  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {

  }
  @HostListener('mouseEnter', ['$event'])
  onMouseEnter() {
    console.log('mouseenter');
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave',['$event'])
  onMouseLeave() {
    console.log('mouseleave');
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p appMouseEvents>
  Hover Mouse over me
</p>
```

When I profile the application in Angular Dev tools, I see that these event cause Angular to trigger change detection which is not needed as only the CSS of host element is affected.
[image]

Is there a way to react to mouse event in the directive and not trigger change detection?

Here's a demo application:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r6ln5w?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Wait why don't you use `:hover` pseudo class to handle this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, event fired on DOM would be monkey patched by zone.js and it triggers a change detection.

I would suggest you to go here using native browser feature. Like use `:hover` pseudo css class on host element.

```
:host:hover {
    // CSS rules
}
```

---

Alternative way to fix it would be using `this.zone.runOutsideAngular` as other suggested answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use NgZone to run code outside of Angular zone (scope) and thus prevent angular change detection https://angular.io/api/core/NgZone

Your directive will look something like this:

```js
    import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMouseEvents]',
})
export class MouseEventsDirective {
  constructor(private element: ElementRef, private zone: NgZone) {
    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      this.element.nativeElement.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
        // e.preventDefault();
        // e.stopPropagation();
        console.log('mouseenter');
      });
    });

    this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      this.element.nativeElement.addEventListener('mouseleave', (e) => {
        // e.preventDefault();
        // e.stopPropagation();
        console.log('mouseleave');
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Here is you stackblitz modified https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-faavr3?file=src/app/mouse-events.directive.ts

Hope this helps.

**Edit: Updated source code**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qvyk2t?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmouse-events.directive.ts

Comment: I still see the change detection cycles being triggered.

Comment: Change detection won't be triggered for the code inside this.zone.runOutsideAngular but will be triggered for the rest of the code. And for your actual use case, a css native solution is maybe more appropriate.

Comment: The code at https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-faavr3?file=src/app/mouse-events.directive.ts causes change detection to be triggered. See - https://imgur.com/a/XQF1hDf

Comment: I have the above answer with working code that does not trigger change detection. See - https://imgur.com/w7TWKPk